# UFW Firewall on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, port, ufw

I have installed UFW on Ubuntu 14.04. I used following commands to enable a port:

```
sudo ufw allow 9384/tcp
```

When I used the status command (sudo ufw status) it shows me that port is open for both IP4 and IP6.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9384/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
9384/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I try to connect Shoutcast it keeps trying to connect to server on port 9384 and eventually disconnects itself. If I turn off the UFW then shoutcast works all fine (connects and streams).

Output of

```
netstat -alpn | grep :9384

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9384            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18235/sc_serv
```

Is there anything specific I should be doing?